# Coordinate systems not lining up

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I am trying to line up a US Census Block shapefile with another shapefile that has lat/long points (i created it from a csv), but the points are not lining up with the Census shapefile.

Here is some info that i can offer:
The census file is in WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere
The points shapefile is in an unprojected lat/long

I have projected the Points shapefile to GCS_WGS_1984
I have projected the Census shapefile to WGS 1984, WGS Web Mercator, NAD 1983, NAD 1983 Albers.

In most scenarios, the points shapefile is either really really small in the center of the map, or off to the side and kind of tilted.

## **Census blocks:**

[image: Census Blocks]

Data Type:    Shapefile Feature Class

Shapefile:    C:\Users\US_blck_grp_2010.shp

Geometry Type:    Polygon

Coordinates have Z values:    No

Coordinates have measures:    No

Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
Projection:    Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere

False_Easting:    0.00000000

False_Northing:    0.00000000

Central_Meridian:    0.00000000

Standard_Parallel_1:    0.00000000

Auxiliary_Sphere_Type:    0.00000000
Linear Unit:     Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:    GCS_WGS_1984

Datum:     D_WGS_1984

Prime Meridian:     Greenwich

Angular Unit:     Degree

## **Points Shapefile:**

[image]

Data Type:    Shapefile Feature Class

Shapefile:    C:\Users\XYrawCA_GISselection.shp

Geometry Type:    Point

Coordinates have Z values:    No

Coordinates have measures:    No

Geographic Coordinate System:    GCS_WGS_1984

Datum:     D_WGS_1984

Prime Meridian:     Greenwich

Angular Unit:     Degree

## Update

This is the image i see when I Reproject the points shapefile to WGS 1984. Technically, its unchanged from when I intitaly load the file. 
[image]

Comment: Did you download the file directly from the Census bureau, or another source? It starts as NAD83 before reprojecting if from Census bureau. Please also confirm that you reprojected (rather than assign/define the projection).

Comment: You're currently in a projected coordinate system with the Census Bureau file (Web Mercator?) and in a geographic coordinate system with the points file (WGS84).

Comment: Hi, yes I downloaded the Census Block Group shapefile from the Census Bureau. And yes, for the Block Group shapefile, i have "reprojected'. For the points shapefile i typically "define projection".  And yes, I do understand that I am running both a PCS and GCS, but im not sure what to do to reconcile the issue. Any reprojection I do seems not to work. Ive also tried "recalculating" the feature extent in ArcCatalog, but it doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: and for what it is worth, i downloaded the blockgroup file from here:
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

Comment: I assume they were merged since I don't recall seeing a full US block group file. My feature extent is different for the block groups, but I think that's because I'm working with CONUS. Let's focus on the XY data. Try reloading it and specifying (during the Display XY Data) what it was collected in (typically WGS84). Then reproject it to match your Census layer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just updated the original post with the results. When I load the points shapefile there is not options for the "Display XY Data". It was a .csv that I exported as a shapefile so I would theoretically be able to manipulate it more easily.

Comment: ok so update for anyone who needs it. i ended up downloading the Census Block Group File from /data2.nhgis.org (the 2016 version) and it appears to work. thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad it's working! I'd re-examine the method you used to export the CSV to shapefile and confirm that general process. If in R, for example, you can set the coordinate system for your output so you won't have to "define" the projection. (Also you probably already noticed but the NHGIS dataset you downloaded is in USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic.)

Comment: Thanks, ill definitely keep that in mind. Your suspicion of the census file was what led me to search for a new one, which ultimately solved the problem. So thanks again!

Comment: There looks to be just enough in comments here for the asker to write a self-answer.